# Error: Integers argument expected, got float

Tags: python, integer, arguments

I've just tried to copy some game code from YouTube. After running the code, it gives the following the error:

> integers argument expected, got float

According to me, the problem is the `w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)` line. What to do?

```
import random
import curses

s = curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0 , 0)
w.keypad(1)
w.timeout(100)

snk_x = sw/4
snk_y = sh/2
snake = [
    [snk_y, snk_x],
    [snk_y, snk_x - 1],
    [snk_y, snk_x - 2]
]

food = [sh/2,sw/2]
w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)
```

Comment: The problem is probably that integer argument expected, got float.
Seriously though, if you divide a number by two, you get a float (in python 3 -- in python 2 it returned an integer if the operands were both integers).

Comment: Use integer division `5 // 2` or `ceil` / `floor` functions from `math` module

Comment: @abdusco `ceil` and `floor` return `floats`.

Comment: No it doesnt: `print(type(ceil(3 / 2)))` prints int as it should.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote them and accept the best one. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Comment: @abdusco ah, it's different in Python 3. Python 2 returns a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's old code, it would have worked on Python 2.

Integer division in Python 2 produces another integer.

In Python 3 it produces a float.

You need to convert the results of the divisions to integers (if that's what's required).

```
snk_x = int(sw / 4)
snk_y = int(sh / 2)
```

and

```
food = [int(sh / 2), int(sw / 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use floor division `//` instead of normal division `/`. The latter always results in a float in Python 3.

`w.addch` is expecting integers.